# Scroll a specific DIV inside a webpage using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

How can we scroll a specific DIV inside a webpage using Selenium WebDriver ? NOT scrolling the complete webpage, BUT scrolling a specific DIV inside the webpage.

for exp:-
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ibm.software.websphere.application-server

- need to "scroll the contents down"

tried:-

```
Actions act2 = new Actions(browser);
WebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar=browser.findElement(By.className("G3J0AAD-b-F"));
act2.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, 250).release().build().perform();
```

This is working but this is not scrolling and it fails sometime by mistakenly clicking some content.

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting my solution which I used for above problem:

1. First click on the scroll-able pane of your page:

   ```java
   Actions clickAction = new Actions(groupBrowser);
   WebElement scrollablePane = groupBrowser.findElement(By
           .className("G3J0AAD-b-F"));
   clickAction.moveToElement(scrollablePane).click().build().perform();
   ```
2. Then scroll with below code:

   ```java
   Actions scrollAction = new Actions(groupBrowser);
   scrollAction.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
   Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
   ```