# Scroll aside div with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, scroll

I'm working on a program that uses Selenium and I'm trying to scroll on some aside `div` of the document.

I firstly tried the following line of code but this only scrolls the main part of the HTML document:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scrollBy(0, 500)");
```

So I tried to execute this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('aside-div')[0].scroll(0,100)");
```

This compile and executes without any error but the section I want to scroll through doesn't scrolls. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll a specific DIV inside a webpage using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764773/scroll-a-specific-div-inside-a-webpage-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to always use the javascript code on your browser console before actual implementation.
*Also, plz make sure scroll(x,y), the value should be according to the scroll it can be either (1000,0) or (0,1000) negative-positive according to the requirement. Kindly choose accordingly.*

[image]

Ok so coming back to your actual problem, what I feel is you are incorrectly using the code

1. Either you have been using scroll(0,1000) instead of scroll(1000,0) so on..
2. You have not mentioned the exact element locator.

> PS: Please provide the HTML for in-depth debugging.

**Meanwhile, you can checkout the below code:**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('aside-div'[0].scroll(0,1000)");
//OR
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('aside-div'[0].scroll(1000,0)");
//OR
WebElement elementToScroll = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".aside-div"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scroll(1000,0);", elementToScroll);
```

**Please provide the exact element locator to use below code:**

**Example**:

```
 WebElement elementToScroll = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".aside-div table tr td"));
//This will scroll the page Horizontally till the element is found
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elementToScroll);
```