# How to scroll down intro element view with selenium+javascript

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing

Im just new in javascript. I used to work with selenium+java. Now I want to perform scroll using JavaScriptExecutor.
How do I make it in javascript code instead of java?

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);
```

Comment: plz check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66249030/5372079

Answer (score 0):

```
//scroll down with Javascript first
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("selector")));
//interact with your element
element.click()
```